# Variables in jQuery with Google events tracking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm building a simple bit of jQuery to use with Google events tracking, and everything works up until the `ga` function -- I thought I could just place the variables in the function, but it's not working. I know because if I use an alert to display the variables before the ga function, I get the alert. But, if I place the alert after the line, it doesn't work.

```
jQuery('.button[data-track="true"').click(function() {
        var eventCategory = jQuery(this).data("category");
        var eventAction = jQuery(this).data("action");
        var eventLabel = jQuery(this).data("label");
        ga('send', 'event', eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel);
});
```

This is an example Google gives:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
});
```

Anyway to use the variables in the `ga` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem using variables in the `ga()` call. Looks like `ga()` hasn't been defined.

1. Do you see any errors in either in a Firebug console or Chrome Dev tools console?
2. `ga()` is part of the new Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`) -- you've got the code snippet for analytics.js in your head, not ga.js, right?
3. You should be able to type `ga` in a console window (Firebug or Chrome Dev tools) and see a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your reference to the Google API is before your JS that needs it.